# log4net: How to read configuration from SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'd like to store log4net.config in a sql server database but not in file.
And
Can log4net read the config from the sql server database?
How to modify this?

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

Comment: On start of your application  read the setting from your sql storage, create a local xml file and feed that to your log4net configuration?

Comment: You are right , but my idea is: to create SQL CLR procedure +log4net for writing log from T-SQL. So I want to avoid file system, first of all the log4net.config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your config data from database and by using *log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure* set log4net configurations during on start your app

```
var configData = DataBaseHelper.GetConfigDataFromDataBase();
using (var MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configData))
{ 
     log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(ms);
}
```

Comment: Great. One thing: This  var configData = DataBaseHelper.GetConfigDataFromDataBase(); can be simple reading nvarchar (MAX) field from a database?

Comment: here shown sample method, which you will create it in your source, it result will be as string

Comment: @MansurKurtov, you can store the config xml in a column of type xml or nvarchar(MAX). One of the [Configure method overloads](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_Config_XmlConfigurator_Configure_9.htm) takes an `XmlElement`.